# Number list formatting followed by code formatting issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question, editing, formatting

On [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/object-oriented-javascript-optimization), I found that when I tried to edit the question and add a numbered list format, it sucked in the code formatting that followed, so I had to add `Code:` after the list to show the numbered list that I wanted to close it.  This allowed the code formatting to start fresh.

Comment: I don't know if this happens in any of the other Stack Sites so I posted it here rather than the Stack Exchange Meta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is the same on all Stack Exchange sites, and it is documented in the [editing help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help). A list item continues until a line is reached that has no indent. This allows you to have multiple paragraphs, quoted text, and code blocks inside a list item.

If you want to follow a numbered list by a code block (without the code block becoming part of the list item), put an HTML comment after the list and before the code block, like this:

```
1. numbered list
1. numbered list

<!-- comment here -->

    code block
    code block
```

Comment: thank you for that insight

Comment: I did not know about this!  Thanks. +1